# Entity Framework table updates not working due to trigger calling CLR

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table with a trigger that points to an assembly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[triggername] ON [dbo].[tablename]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AFTER DELETE, UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
```

AS EXTERNAL NAME [Namofassembly].[blahblah].[blahblah]

We also using code first EF in .net 4.
When I use delete everything works fine but the trigger does not get called.

```
dataRepo.UsersPermanentAuditAssignments.Remove(isInsertFound)
```

When I use update I get a permissions error. This is either when I try it through the object model or a dataRepo.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(updateSql)

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The context transaction which was active before entering user defined routine, trigger or aggregate "name" has been ended inside of it, which is not allowed. Change application logic to enforce strict transaction nesting.
```

Everything works fine when I run the queries via the sql management studio.

I also am not able to change this configuration so while I don't care for this design I am not able to change it.

My questions are:
1> Why would the delete not get logged but work?

2> Do I need to add something extra to my repo configuration object that will allow this to work? Do I need to add some transaction like unitofwork before I start this since it has a trigger maybe?

Comment: Are you sure that your app is connecting to the same database that you're running the query against in SSMS? "Trust, but verify" by running a trace and ensuring that your app is indeed doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the causes of this issue.
It relates to having a composite primary key (station,user) and trying to update one of the values.

I could not update any column of the primary key, ie change the user assigned to a station.
The trigger failure masked the issue of not being able to update a value inside the key.
My experiments show the following for the compositekey/pk update:

```
Method          History Trigger            Result
EF.SaveChanges              Enabled        Fail at trigger
EF.SaveChanges              Disabled        Fail at trigger
EF.ExecuteSQLCommand(sql)   Enabled        Fail at trigger
EF.ExecuteSQLCommand(sql)   Disabled       Works
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to change to a surrogate with a unique index which would work. Also, the trigger CLR prevents me from using DataBase.ExecuteSQLCommand(sql) also which I believe is actually a problem with the CLR of which I have not ability to modify.

So my advise (that I can't take) is if you get this use a surrogate key and a unique index instead of combining the 2.

If anyone knows any way to allow EF to allow you to change a value inside a composite/primary key please comment.